# QT QListWidget.addItem(..) - When the item be freed or does QT take care of it

Tags: memory-leaks, qt4

I am adding items that are on the heap to a QListWidget, using the addItem(QListWidetItem *) method.

I cannot find any documentation indicating if QT manages the items memory and frees it when the item is removed from the list,  or if the my application code should track and delete the item.

What is the requirement? Can anyone point me to concise documentation on QT and memory management to avoid leaks.

Comment: Found this which answers my question. [link](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/objecttrees.html)

Comment: Also found the documentation for adding QActions to a QMenu explicitly states the QMenu does not take ownership of the item. Therefore it seems that when QT docs do not mention ownership, it implies that the QWidget item does take ownership.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation ist quite sketchy on this one.
Fact is, that the QListWidget takes ownership over the item and deletes it, or attempts to delete it if you `clear()` the view for example.

I found out about this by looking at the Qt code after I ran into a similar problem.
The only indication to this in the documentation is that there is a warning issued that you mustn't add the same item twice.